# Why does my view query split into two?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a view that records the selected attributes for all Computer Science majors.

This is my query to create a view:

```
DROP VIEW   CS_grade_report;

CREATE VIEW CS_grade_report AS
SELECT      Student.student_id AS "ID", 
            student_name AS "Name", 
            course_number AS "Course #", 
            credit AS "Credit", 
            grade AS Grade
FROM        Student, Class, Enrolls
WHERE       major = 'CSCI'
AND         Student.student_id = Enrolls.student_id
AND         Class.schedule_num = Enrolls.schedule_num;

SELECT  *
FROM    CS_grade_report;
```

And this is what is generated:

```
ID     Name                      Course #     Credit GR
------ ------------------------- -------- ---------- --
600000 John Smith                CSCI3200          4 B+
600000 John Smith                CSCI3700          3 C
600000 John Smith                SPAN1004          3 A-
600000 John Smith                CSCI4300          3 A+
600001 Andrew Tram               MUSC2406          2 A+
600001 Andrew Tram               SPAN1004          3 A
600001 Andrew Tram               CSCI3700          3 B-
600002 Jane Doe                  CSCI4200          3 D+
600003 Michael Jordan            CSCI4300          3 A+
600004 Tiger Woods               MUSC1000          1 A
600007 Dominique Davis           CSCI4300          3 F

ID     Name                      Course #     Credit GR
------ ------------------------- -------- ---------- --
600009 Will Smith                CSCI3200          4 A
600010 Papa Johns                CSCI3200          4 B
600011 John Doe                  CSCI3200          4 C
600012 Jackie Chan               CSCI3200          4 D
600013 Some Guy                  CSCI3200          4 E

16 rows selected.
```

Comment: Where are you running the SELECT from ?

Comment: Running in sqlplus?  Try `SET PAGESIZE 50` for 50 lines to a page, look at sqlplus ref manual for all kinds of ways to change column formatting, headings, etc. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1011230

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this is output from sqlplus.  There is a "pagesize" option to define when breaks are added.  If you only want to see one heading, set the size to a large enough value prior to running your SELECT statement as such:

```
set pagesize 500
```

(or whatever size you want)

There are many command options for sqlplus.  This [link](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-set.html) is a good cheat-sheet.